# adding bitwise and with column in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I tried to do this but this.

```
Building.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'bitwise'],
    where: Sequelize.and(
        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('bitwise & 2'), '!=', 0),
        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('bitwise & 4'), '=', 0)
    )
})
```

but this is not working with sequelize v4 API.

I tried to write it something like this

```
Subscription.findAll({
  where: { [Op.and]: { status: "active", Sequelize.literal(`deliveryBitMask & 1`), '=', 0 }
})
```

It gives me an unexpected token error.

How can we pass a literal object to sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AND with an array of conditions like so:

```
Subscription.findAll({
  where: { [Op.and]: [ {status: "active"}, Sequelize.literal("deliveryBitMask & 1 = 0")] }
})
```

It doesn't seem to be possible to mix literal with operators (like `=`) from whatever examples I've seen. But I'm not 100% sure because the docs aren't comprehensive.

Comment: when I execute this. It seems to generate write SQL query here

Executing (default): SELECT "id",  "deliveryBitMask", "qty",  "status", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Subscriptions" AS "Subscription" WHERE ("Subscription"."status" = 'active' AND deliveryBitMask & 1 = 1);


but then later it throws error 

SequelizeDatabaseError: column "deliverybitmask" does not exist

I am not able to understand why it converted deliveryBitMask to smallcase

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to above answer

```
Subscription.findAll({
  where: { [Op.and]: [ {status: "active"}, Sequelize.literal("deliveryBitMask & 1 = 0")] }
})

Executing (default): SELECT "id", "deliveryBitMask", "qty", "status", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Subscriptions" AS "Subscription" WHERE ("Subscription"."status" = 'active' AND deliveryBitMask & generate
```

This will generte query like this.

but it converts column deliveryBitMask as query literal is not quoted. so use escape character for the quote in a query string
PostgreSQL converts all table column names into lowercase, unless quoted.